# Bluetooth - no audio on phone calls

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 17.04

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04, with PulseAudio 10.0 and ofono 1.19. I'm trying to make phone call using ofono from my PC. When I make call I can see in pavucontrol that profile is changed to HSP/HFP, but the is no audio on PC speakers. There is an audio output on the phone side.

Extra information:

```
$ pactl list sources short

0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
1   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
4   bluez_sink.48_59_29_1F_74_9B.headset_audio_gateway.monitor  module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 1ch 8000Hz    RUNNING
5   bluez_source.48_59_29_1F_74_9B.headset_audio_gateway    module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 1ch 8000Hz    RUNNING

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ pactl list sinks short

0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
1   bluez_sink.48_59_29_1F_74_9B.headset_audio_gateway  module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 1ch 8000Hz    RUNNING
```

I found this error in syslog:

```
[pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Could not activate new audio connection as it is already active!? (path=/card_1 fd=55, codec=1, transport [state=playing, profile=headset_audio_gateway])
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it? I seem to have a similar problem. Appreciated if you helped: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468780/pulseaudio-setting-up-sinks-and-sources-for-a2dp-and-hfp-connections#468780

Comment: Also for me, Linux Mint 19 with Blueman app and pulseaudio. I paired Moto C Plus via bluetooth and I can listen to music from phone, but when calling it becomes mute...